# Reload view after a certain IBAction (iOS + Parse)

Tags: ios, parse-platform

After deleting a Product my app takes me to the Root View Controller where I have a Collection View of all my products. Is there a way to reload the Root View Controller ONLY after a certain action? (Like deleting a product).

Thanks.

**StoreViewController** (Root View Controller)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Deadstock", nil);

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[ProductCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ProductCell"];

    [self loadProducts];
}

- (void)loadProducts {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Product"];
    [query orderByAscending:@"size"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            [self.collectionView reloadData];

            self.products = objects;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}
```

**ProductViewController**

```
- (IBAction)deleteProduct:(id)sender {
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil) style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {}];
    UIAlertAction *deleteAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Delete Product", nil) style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        [self.product deleteInBackground];

        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }];

    [alertController addAction:cancelAction];
    [alertController addAction:deleteAction];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Is there a way to reload a view after an IBAction?

Comment: You want to reload your collectionView?

Comment: Yeah the Collection View @Shoaib

Comment: did you try collectionView.reloadData() after updating the main array? isn't it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From not knowing the entire stack of your application, the easiest way to do this is:

```
//call this whenever you want to reload the root view controller
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReloadData" object:nil];
```

And then:

```
//place this in your root view controller class
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loadProducts) name:@"ReloadData" object:nil];
```

Comment: It works! Thanks for the quick response... So NSNotificationCenter is basically telling the view to run "loadProducts" after the IBAction?

Comment: Yeah, basically it broadcasts the message across the whole app and whenever a class is registered to listen for that message, you can decide which method to call (in this case, loadProducts). Mind upvoting and selecting my answer as correct?

Comment: Can you accept as correct answer? Would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The notification AlexKoren posted will work if you want to explicitly call it from anywhere in the app. The downside is multiple notifications can become difficult to trace and debug after the app becomes more complex.

Another option would be a delegate protocol in which you implement a didDelete handler. The handler calls loadProducts on the specified controller, then set that controller as your delegate. This allows multiple controllers to perform the same delegate action without creating full inter-class dependency.

A more simple implementation may be to just pass a callback for the reload function when creating the product controller, allowing the reload call to be handled in the product controller's dismissal or upon whichever action you might want to take.

Having tried all 3 in several apps, I think the delegate method and option 2 are easiest to maintain and more closely in line with how standard iOS frameworks behave (for example: didSelectRowAtIndexPath for tableview delegates). An added benefit might be animating the removal if a particular index is also specified and passed back to the delegate.